# Mongoose plugin with preselected filter

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-plugins

Is it possible to create a mongoose plugin that in every query it will add a standard filter?

I want every time a make a User.find() or User.findOne() or User.update() or User.delete() etc... to include everytime this filter { activated: true }

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it in our team is we have a `UsersManager` class which implements methods like `find` or `fineOne`, and those methods call `mongoose`'s methods while adding the base filters. For example:

```
class UsersManager {
    find(filter) {
        return userModel.find()
            .where('activated', true)
            .where(filter)
            .exec();
    }
}
```

No other class will ever call `userModel.find` directly.

If you need to add the same filter on every method, you should consider using a utility method.